# Unable to turn on log_bin database flag for replica instances of GCP Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Unable to turn on log_bin database flag in Cloud SQL for replica instances.
If I am reading this correctly, it says I can turn on binlog's for a
replica. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication#bin-log-replica

However, when I try to turn it on, I get an invalid flag. We are on MySQL
5.7. Using: log_bin=on

Also tried this CL-
gcloud sql instances patch [relica_instance_name] --enable-bin-log

Comment: Hi, the command you shared is the one that helps to enable the bin logs. Do you get an error trying to execute it? If so, could you please share the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The binlogs for a replica are enabled by configuring point-in-time recovery on the Master (Source) MySQL instance.
Once the Master has completed a PIT snapshot, you can enable the flags in the replica instances.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/pitr#enablingpitr

Answer (score 0):

I was able to turn binary logs on a read replica instance using GCP CLI:

```
gcloud sql instances patch mydb-production-v2-replica --enable-bin-log
```